FAILURE: The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher
For some reason my build.gradle doesn't look the same as the other solutions i found online, so I'm not sure if I edited it correctly. I just added the buildscript segment to the top of the file; however, I'm still getting the same error.
Error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':pdf_merger' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.31

build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.diagnosis"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.diagnosis"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

Android Studio Error:
Multiple build operations failed.
    Could not create task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
    Could not create task ':url_launcher_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
Could not create task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
this and base files have different roots: D:\App_Dev\flutter_projects\diagnosis\build\path_provider_android and C:\Users\ziadg\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\path_provider_android-2.2.4\android.


"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

This issue arises from incompatibility between the Gradle and Kotlin versions.
Here's the solution:

Upgrade the Gradle plugin version within your build.gradle file:
/// Your current version
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
/// Change to
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'


Update the Gradle version specified in the gradle-wrapper.properties file:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip





Unsupported class file major version 64
changing the gradle JVM. Settings... -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle then downgrade the Gradle JVM

The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:

in you pdf_merger project, open the build.gradle file, then change the ext.kotlin_version to '1.5.20'

I get the same error with this solution. When I try ./gradlew clean build I get: `* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.

BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'D:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\app_plugin_loader.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 64`


this is an other error msg : "Unsupported class file major version 64". You should update your gradle version in the following steps :
Settings... -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle then downgrade the Gradle JVM. I also add a picture to answer

I'm assuming I have to use the JVM version in the picture. I still get the same error. I added a picture and the android studio error to the post.

"The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':pdf_merger' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.31." This is another error after you change you jvm/gradle version. When you current kotlin version is higher much than 'pdf_merger''s kotlin version, this error will occur. Don't worry, let's fix it step by step, it seems a new project without any private code, just give the github link, I would make an MR(Merge Request) if you don't mind.

in Android Studio use:
Ctrl + Shift + F
Find all your kotlin plugins '1.4.31', and change the 1.4.31 to 1.5.20

I get the same errors with a fresh project. I'm complete noob with GitHub, but here goes: https://github.com/zgeez/flutter_test

I've add the solution to my answer and run your project successful. in you pdf_merger project, open the build.gradle file, then change the ext.kotlin_version to '1.5.20', that will works

the actual reason you meet the problem is the flutter library https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_merger/versions  you use in android, use the lower kotlin version that doesn't meet the minimum requirements.
